# Save sequence images to iphone

Tags: iphone

I make screen shot with iphone camera use the UIGetScreenImage()method, I want to make this images sequence to video, but the memory is limited , i think write the image data to documents maybe a good choice for me. so when capture the image use UIGetSreenImage(), start a new thread to write the image data to documents, but this will delay the thread which used to capture image.

I don't know how to deal with this issues, Would you give me some advises? any reply will appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Foremost, I'd stay away from UIGetScreenImage() if you can, at least if you plan on releasing your app to the App Store.  UIGetScreenImage() is not a public API, and it's one of the most likely "forbidden" APIs that Apple would reject your app for using.

If you want a screen shot (i.e. what the user sees on the device's screen), I think the approach that you've laid out works well, but you're going to need to get a graphic representation of the UIView that contains all your other views.

All UIView code must be on the main thread, though.  You can do your file I/O on the background thread, but the actual getting of the image will have to be main thread.

Answer (score 0):

How about NSOperationQueue?

Whenever the screen is captured and an image is created, an NSOperation which writes an image into documents is added a NSOperationQueue.

And I think you should find the best number of the max concurrent operation count (NSOperation's setMaxConcurrentOperationCount).

The max concurrent operation count depends on your app.